.NET 8 application file written gets lost after a while
I have a .NET 8 application which, among other things, has the following functionality: it contains a hosted service that fetches some records from a database, produces some .txt files and writes them on the path /mnt/import. The background service must run on a specified interval.
The code for the background service look like this
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace ArrivalConfirmation.ExporterService.Shared.Hosting.Abstractions;

public class ScheduledBackgroundService(TimeSpan period) : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly PeriodicTimer _timer = new(period);

    public TimeSpan Period { get; } = period;

    /// <summary>Contains the logic that runs at the specified time interval.</summary>
    /// <param name="stoppingToken">Triggered when <see cref="IHostedService.StopAsync(CancellationToken)"/> is called.</param>
    /// <returns>A <see cref="ValueTask"/> representing the asynchronous operation.</returns>
    private ValueTask RunLoopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) 
    {
        /* Other code removed for brevity. */
        await File.WriteAllTextAsync(path, content);
    }

    /// <summary>Calls the <see cref="RunLoopAsync(CancellationToken)"/> method at the specified time interval.</summary>
    /// <param name="stoppingToken">Triggered when <see cref="IHostedService.StopAsync(CancellationToken)"/> is called.</param>
    protected override sealed async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested && await _timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(stoppingToken)) {
            await RunLoopAsync(stoppingToken);
        }
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override void Dispose() {
        _timer.Dispose();
        base.Dispose();
    }
}

The weird thing is that when this code runs it works as expected locally, but when deployed to production, the files are written, but are lost after a short period of time.
The application runs on Azure Kuberneres Service and when deployed a docker image is used. This image is nothing special, it is just the image created from the default Dockerfile provided by Visual Studio.
On the aforementioned path, a persistent volume is mounted. I have tried to write files from the command line in k8s and the files remain after pod up or down. The even more strange thing is that when I tried to write files outside the scope of the background service the files also stay and not deleted. But when the same code runs inside a background service the files are deleted automatically after some seconds.
Does anyone have any clue what can cause this behavior? Thanks in advance.

path and content are not defined in this code?

@topsail yes they are defined. I just did not put this code or brevity as said in the code comment.

You will need to provide the missing details.
